# How to listen java script fired event from angularjs function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am implementing an online yaml code editor. I want to convert yaml code to and json object real time. I have used following java script function for it.

```
editor.getSession().on('change', function(e) {

try{
    nativeObject = YAML.parse(editor.getValue());
    var out  = nativeObject.toString();
    //window.alert(editor.getValue());
    //console.log(out);
    //document.getElementById("documentation").innerHTML=editor.getValue();
    //window.alert(nativeObject);

    //fire the event

    if ("createEvent" in document) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    else
        element.fireEvent("onchange");

}catch(e2) {
    //window.alert("Syntax Error");
    swal("Syntax Error", "Please check your yaml syntaxes!", "error");

}

});
```

Then I set this json elements to html page using angularjs. How do I write an angularjs function to listen above fired event? I have used this angularjs function but it didn't work properly

```
$scope.$on('onchange',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('sample.json').success(function(response){
        $scope.myData = response;
        //console.log("good");
    });
});
```

Comment: you can wrap your logic from the first code in a directive / service and use angular events on $rootScope instead of creating event in the script